# How to do this transformation $Y= g(x) \sim \mathcal U(0,2)$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)=2(1-x)$ for $0 < x < 1$, find the transformation $Y=g(X)$ such that
the random variable $Y\sim \mathcal U(0,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Probability Integral Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) to get the standard uniform distribution and then scale it accordingly. There might be other ways but I believe this is the fastest. Try it and let us know if you come across any problems.

Comment: Exactly the approach I'd recommend. +1